# Keras Dropout Convolutional Filters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, dropout

I understand that [dropout doesn't have the same effect for kernels of convolutional filters of a neural network, as it does for FC layers](https://towardsdatascience.com/dropout-on-convolutional-layers-is-weird-5c6ab14f19b2):

But does the same fact apply, if you dropout the whole filter?

Let's assume a network structure like: Input, Conv2D, Conv2D, ..., Conv2D, Conv2D, Sigmoid. So there is no fully connected Layer in the whole network.

**Question 1**
Is it reasonable  to apply conv filter dropouts to avoid co-adaptation between filters for improving the results of [filter visualization](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-visualize-convolutional-features-in-40-lines-of-code-70b7d87b0030).

**Question 2**
Is there a quick way to do dropout filters in keras.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1** Maybe.

Without Dropout:
[image]

With Dropout:
[image]

**Answer 2** 
According to the [keras documentations](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dropout) states, use `keras.layers.Dropout(rate, noise_shape=None, seed=None)` with `noise_shape=(batch_size, 1, 1, features)`. Use 1 if you want the dropout mask to be the same for a complete dimension.